# Distance between caption and figure

Tags: floats, captions

I have used this code but there is unsuitable distance between caption and figure. Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{solpro.pdf} 
 \caption{flowchart of solution procees}
 \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: then your image has some whitespace at the bottom!

Comment: You should edit your post. Could we see  what is an `unsuitable distance`? This probably is not due to LaTeX, but to a wrong bouding box of the image, i.e. unwanted white space at the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[skip=.5em]{caption} %use skip=<whatever you like>

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{solpro.pdf}
 \rule{34mm}{55mm}% test image
 \caption{flowchart of solution procees}
 \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```